# Trouble Returning List of string of all looped xml elements in function

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, multidimensional-array

I am trying to make this function return a (list/multidarray) of the 7 BranchHours.childnodes for this branchID that I can call with a little code in my codebehind page.

here is what one section of the xmlfile looks like (BranchesInfo)

```xml
<BranchInfo>
    <BranchId>db</BranchId>
    <Name></Name>
    <ShortName></ShortName>
    <ImageUrl></ImageUrl>
    <BranchHours>
      <Hours>
        <DayOfWeek>Sunday</DayOfWeek>
        <Open>12:00</Open>
        <Close>5:00</Close>
      </Hours>
      <Hours>
        <DayOfWeek>Monday</DayOfWeek>
        <Open>10:00</Open>
        <Close>8:00</Close>
      </Hours>
      <Hours>
        <DayOfWeek>Tuesday</DayOfWeek>
        <Open>10:00</Open>
        <Close>8:00</Close>
      </Hours>
      <Hours>
        <DayOfWeek>Wednesday</DayOfWeek>
        <Open>10:00</Open>
        <Close>8:00</Close>
      </Hours>
      <Hours>
        <DayOfWeek>Thursday</DayOfWeek>
        <Open>10:00</Open>
        <Close>6:00</Close>
      </Hours>
      <Hours>
        <DayOfWeek>Friday</DayOfWeek>
        <Open>10:00</Open>
        <Close>6:00</Close>
      </Hours>
      <Hours>
        <DayOfWeek>Saturday</DayOfWeek>
        <Open>12:00</Open>
        <Close>5:00</Close>
      </Hours>
    </BranchHours>
</BranchInfo>
```

code

```vb
'app_code function below 
Public Shared Function MyFunc(ByVal branchCode As String) As List(Of String)

    Dim URLString As String = "url/branchesTesting.xml" 

    Dim xmlDoc As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(URLString)

    XDocument.Load(URLString)
    Dim labelMan As List(Of String)
    Dim x As Integer = (0) 'looping variable
    ' Dim i As Integer = 1
    Dim branchid = xmlDoc.XPathSelectElements("/BranchesInfo/BranchInfo[BranchId='" & branchCode & "']/BranchHours/Hours")

    'Dim varList As New List(Of String)
    Dim Items = From BranchHours In xmlDoc.XPathSelectElements("/BranchesInfo/BranchInfo[BranchId='" & branchCode & "']/BranchHours/Hours") _
    Select DayOfWeek = (BranchHours.Elements("DayOfWeek").Value),
    Open = (BranchHours.Elements("Open").Value), _
    Close = (BranchHours.Elements("Close").Value)

    '  Dim lists = xmlDoc.Root.Elements("BranchHours").[Select](Function(element) element.Value).ToList()
    For Each Hours In Items
    '   For i As Integer = 0 To Items.Count - 1
        '   lists = labelMan
        labelMan = "<div>DayOfWeek:" & Hours.DayOfWeek & "Open:" & Hours.Open & "Close: " & Hours.Close & "</div>" ' ----- error Error  34  Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of String)'.

    '  Else
        '     i += 1
    ' End If
        labelMan = labelMan
    'Next
    Next
    '  If labelMan = "" Then
        'labelMan = "No Results."
    'End If

    Return labelMan  
End Fuction

Public Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Call BranchHours.branchHours.MyFunc("dr")

    Label1.Text = BranchHours.branchHours.MyFunc("dr") ' ----- Error Error  35  Value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of String)' cannot be converted to 'String'. 

End Sub
```

Ideal Results

```
Day of the Week     Open    Close
(0)Sunday           12:00   5:00
(1)Monday           10:00   8:00
(2)Tuesday          10:00   8:00
(3)Wednesday        10:00   8:00
(4)Thursday         10:00   6:00
(5)Friday           10:00   6:00
(6)Saturday         10:00   5:00
```

--- the (i) would not be visible its for referencing the results in the future.

please let me know if you need any additional information. Thank you!

Comment: You didn't show us how `MyFunc` is declared, but it looks like it is expecting a `List(Of String)` as an argument and you are passing a `String` ("dr"),

Comment: myfunc is declared in my app_code folder - Correct me if I'm wrong but  its expecting a string ("dr") and looking to for the return value to be a List(of string) from retrun labelMan?              Public Shared Function MyFunc(ByVal branchCode As String)  As List(Of String)      and in my code behind page 'code' Public Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Call BranchHours.branchHours.MyFunc("dr")

 

        Label1.Text = BranchHours.branchHours.MyFunc("dr") -- Conversion from type 'List(Of String)' to type 'String' is not valid.
    End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to instantiate your List(of String).  Right now for you it is Nothing.

```
Dim labelMan As List(Of String) = New List(of String)
```

Then you need to use the [List(of T) Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
labelMan.Add("<div>DayOfWeek:" & Hours.DayOfWeek & "Open:" & Hours.Open & "Close: " & Hours.Close & "</div>")
```

Comment: Thank you, I am no longer showing any errors in my function now.  I debugging trying to fix this error right after calling the function in my codebehind page                                                             `code`    Label1.Text = BranchHours.branchHours.MyFunc("dr")   --- Error 36 Value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of String)' cannot be converted to 'String'.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help resolve your question.  If it truly did answer your question, please mark it as the accepted answer.  Label1.Text is a String, so instead of making MyFunc return a List(of String) you should have it return a String.  The Types need to match.  A List(of String) is not a String.

Comment: Here the solution I came up with to call and display myfunc().          
`code` Public Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Call BranchHours.branchHours.MyFunc("dr")
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        Dim rangex As List(Of String) = BranchHours.branchHours.MyFunc("dr")
        Dim message = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, rangex.ToList())


        For Each Items As String In rangex
            ' Do something with items
            Label1.Text = message

        Next
    End Sub

Answer (score 0):

**Thanks Again to those who helped me. Here the complete answer w/ comments:)**

side note -- This code will be audited, so for those who can see places that I should add testing or should make improvement in the code below. Please feel free to advise/comment.

App_Code Function >

```
Namespace BranchHours
    Public Class branchHours

        'function will accecpt string of branch ID and return value to be a List(of string)
        Public Shared Function MyFunc(ByVal branchCode As String) As List(Of String)
            'set XML URL path
            Dim URLString As String = "url/branchesTesting.xml"
            'load URL Path
            Dim xmlDoc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(URLString)

            ' instantiate List(of String)
            Dim labelMan As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
            'define items start path in xml document based on passsed branchcode id
            'select and set xml element variable and return value/innertext for branch hours
            Dim Items = From BranchHours In xmlDoc.XPathSelectElements("/BranchesInfo/BranchInfo[BranchId='" & branchCode & "']/BranchHours/Hours") _
            Select DayOfWeek = (BranchHours.Elements("DayOfWeek").Value),
            Open = (BranchHours.Elements("Open").Value), _
            Close = (BranchHours.Elements("Close").Value) _
            'BranchID = (branchname.Elements("BranchId").Value)

            For Each Hours In Items
                ' use the List(of T) Add method: to add each hours' nodes to list, you can also add some html tags here if you to style it a bit more then plain text
                labelMan.Add(Hours.DayOfWeek & "," & Hours.Open & "," & Hours.Close)

            Next

            Return labelMan
        End Function


    End Class
End Namespace
```

Code Behind >

```
     Public Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
' this line will call one of the specified list items
            Label2.Text = BranchHours.branchHours.MyFunc("dr").ElementAt(1)


            Call BranchHours.branchHours.MyFunc("dr")
'This block below will return the full list of branchhours
        Dim i As Integer = 0

        Dim rangex As List(Of String) = BranchHours.branchHours.MyFunc("dr")
        Dim message = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, rangex.ToList())


        For Each Items As String In rangex
           ' Do something with items
           Label1.Text = message


        'Next
    End Sub
```

Front .aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default3bh.aspx.vb" Inherits="Default3bh" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">

    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
</asp:Content>


<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="AdditionalContent" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
```

Results >

```
Label2 : Monday,10:00,6:00

label1 : Sunday,Closed,Closed Monday,10:00,6:00 Tuesday,10:00,8:00 Wednesday,10:00,6:00 Thursday,10:00,6:00 Friday,10:00,6:00 Saturday,10:00,5:00
```